# Shutter - Error while opening directory '/home/username/Pictures'

Tags: ubuntu, screenshot, ubuntu-16.04, shutter, invalid-url

I am using Shutter, and I absolutely loved it. I installed it in my new laptop and unable to get it working. When I open shutter and try to take a screenshot, it shows me error message saying "Error while opening /home/username/Pictures'.

[image]

[image]

I have tried changing the path to save it somewhere else but still the same issue. I can go to the terminal and create a file in this folder without any issue. So, it doesn't feel like it's a permission issue.

I have also tried to autoremove and purge shutter and install it again multiple times. But it didn't solve the issue. Any guidance would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you saving output image to different location? If so, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1mfzkj/problem_with_shutter/?st=j6cyjqr9&sh=3fb145aa) suggests to leave off the -o

Comment: What version of shutter, out of curiosity?

Comment: [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shutter/+bug/1069590) may also be helpful?

Comment: @TriskalJM Version is 0.93.1 Rev.1278

Comment: @user2798227 did you try the suggestion at the link I posted?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it seems that some dependencies were not installed for shutter for me. After installing shutter from the command line:

```
$ sudo apt-get install shutter
```

it worked again.

Comment: I have tried removing and installing shutter a number of times.

Comment: I also changed the group of my pictures folder, because it belonged to a wider group than my user's group, maybe that was the solution or we have different issues than :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in my pc by creating the folder manually it is looking for.
In your case create folder **mohit/Pictures** in side **/home** folder and restart shutter application.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue and tried the same way you did by purging the whole app...
but well, actually the problem was i moved my pictures folder by mistake, after i put it back in the original location it worked again perfect, so that could be the reason in case anyone having the same problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).